# Segmentation Fault problema Caesar del curso CS50

Tags: c

Estoy creando un programa para encriptar un texto desde la command line, pero al darle todos los inputs que solicita el programa, me arroja Segmentation Fault.

Dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        string ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(plaintext); j++)
        {
            if (isalpha(plaintext[j]) == true)
            {
                if (isupper(plaintext[j]) == true)
                {
                    ciphertext[j] = (plaintext[j] - 65 + argv[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n", ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un VLA y es una característica no soportada por el estándar de C:

```
string ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];
```

En algunos compiladores puede funcionar como esperas mientras que en el resto obtendrás errores en tiempo de compilación o fallos al ejecutar el programa

En C, los arrays deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, no es tu caso. Cuando el tamaño únicamente se puede conocer en tiempo de ejecución es preferible usar `malloc`:

```
string ciphertext = (string)malloc(strlen(plaintext) * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Hola Eferion. Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero al poner el codigo que me dices, termina en el mismo resultado: "Segmentation Fault". Estoy tratando de leer sobre malloc, pero aún no lo entiendo bien.

Comment: @AntonioCoder cuales son los parámetros que usas para ejecutar el programa? No me respondas por comentarios, edita la pregunta y avísame

Comment: Perdón eferion, pero soy muy principiante y no se a que te refieres con los parámetros. Al compilar le quiero dar "./caesar" y "numero que represente argv[1]". Me dices y edito la pregunta.